# Dynamically changing number of form elements with PHP variables

Tags: php, forms, dynamic

I would like to be able to dynamically change how many option values are available,  so that there are always "$i" values, like in the following.

```
<form action="scheduled.php" method="post" id="fields">
        <p>Teams Playing</p>
            <SELECT NAME="Teams[]" MULTIPLE SIZE=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($i); ?>> 
                <OPTION value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($team[0]); ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($team[0]); ?>
                <OPTION value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($team[1]); ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($team[1]); ?>
                <OPTION value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($team[2]); ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($team[2]); ?>
                <OPTION value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($team[3]); ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($team[3]); ?>
                ...
                <OPTION value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($team[$i]); ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($team[$i]); ?>
            </SELECT>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

I already suspect my code is sloppy for using all of the "?php echo"s. Is there any way I can make a for loop so that there are always "$i" options displayed in this format?

Comment: Use a loop to iterate over the $team array and print your select options.

Comment: Write the answer in the answer section new time, it'll be clearer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Here was my solution:

```
<form action="scheduled.php" method="post" id="fields">
    <p>Teams Playing</p>
        <SELECT NAME="Teams[]" MULTIPLE SIZE=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($i); ?>>
            <?php
                for ($x=0; $x<$i; $x++){
                    echo "<OPTION value=".htmlspecialchars($team[$x]).";>";
                    echo $team[$x];
                } 

            ?>
        </SELECT>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```